# Cannot re-send an IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I've just released production code which allows our user to purchase something using Paypal payment buttons.

After a quick test transaction, I've realized that the address I want my IPN is slightly incorrect and my IPN is not being received by my system.

According to this article, I should be able to just re-send it to my profile IPN URL.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNOperations/#resend-ipn-messages

However, after going to the IPN history page, I do not see any option to re-send.

Has the ability to re-send IPN messages been turned off?

Comment: Ok looks like it can't seem to re-send when it's in the Retrying status. How do I set it from Retrying to Failed so I can re-send it with a different address?

Comment: Retrying means it's sending again on its own.  Make sure your IPN script is ready to successfully process the IPNs, and when the next retry happens it'll update to 200 completed.

Comment: @AndrewAngell - The problem is the address where it sends the IPN is wrong and I can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can't re-send an IPN in the status of Retrying and you also cannot tell it to stop Retrying.

So the solution here was to just wait for the status to go to Failed (which it'll do after trying for 4-5 days), then change the IPN URL on your profile to the correct URL, then go to the IPN history, find the failed ones and re-send it.